# Proposing a project redesign

Tags: java, android, software-design

My question is of a generic nature, I'm not even sure if such questions are allowed on SO, but it's been weighing on me for the past couple of months and I couldn't find anything on this elsewhere.  I should mention I'm a junior dev still, and this might be me simply going about this whole thing wrong, but here goes nothing..

I'm currently tasked with the maintenance and further development of an Android application.  The work conducted on it before I took over is best described as "at least it works, but not really".  Bulk of functionality is there, accompanied with tons of little awkward bugs that happen intermittently and other multi-tasking and async behavioral issues and limitations.

No design was agreed upon, which I suppose indicates no proper research having gone into how to structure the whole things and javadoc is nearly non existent. I believe its only present from sources which were imported into this project, not ones made from scratch.

Put in technical terms, it's a crippled MVC featuring an anorexic model (getters, setters, no behavior) and starving views (just the necessary widgets thrown in there) with a buffet of morbidly obese controllers in the form of activities to compensate for it all.  The activities are in charge of handing business logic, user interaction, data manipulation as well as network communication - from parsing the message all the way to firing new activities based on the server's response.

Every issue obviously has to be handled in the activities but the workarounds are becoming more and more restricted and dodgy.  I had another developer maintaining the iOS version weigh in who was quite shocked at the state of things and the senior developer who pretty much said "can't be helped, just do what you can".

So in conclusion and the point of this post is I would like to transfer some meat and bones to the model, allowing it to be in charge of server communication to populate its data, and have its own behavior for both providing to the controller and maintaining itself.  This change would almost entirely decouple the activities from having to directly handle server communication and instead focus on the business logic and user interaction for now.

What do people with **any** experience facing something like this end up doing and how does it turn out?

Comment: You really have 2 choices 1) Do you refactor 2) Do you start from scratch reverse engineering the app.  How you implement the new code is up to you.   Whichever direction you take it must be with testing in mind.  I'm not necessarily talking TDD, but your main problem is that everything is mashed together and unstable/untestable.   A de-coupled approach does sound the right choice (using whichever pattern suits the needs of achieving this the best MVC, MVP, MVVC etc), Removing the Android framework out of your business logic, so your left with pure java will help ease the testing process.

Comment: @MarkKeen is right but there's one crucial thing to take in consideration: **TIME**. Starting from scratch is a good investment but it takes time. Refactoring on the other side might take you less time but that depends... So before starting anything, do some estimations and talk to your employers about it.

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin - things I couldn't possibly know:  resources that are available, time scales etc ...  that's why I said 2 choices - the impact of each will be determined by the OP.

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin Thank you both for your comments.  Starting from scratch is probably not possible.  This would immediately raise alarms that I'm suggesting version 3.0 which might hurt more than help.  Refactoring for the time being is the only choice, I would love to locate some good books on this topic, I've stumbled upon a few websites thus far with interesting information.  I have to read up before I take action, and I have to test and take action **first** before I walk up to management and tell them I have a *great idea*.

Comment: @MarkKeen For clarification, it's just me, as a junior developer on the entire project, No additional help is available as it stands and no documentation or design principles have been made available either as mentioned in the first post.  I believe they're also trying to push for a release soon and I don't blame them, this must have been in the works for quite a long time now.

Comment: I don't see how a release can be pushed soon if nothing has really been estimated or tested (releases are made with known bugs?) - it will just perpetuate the current situation?  I suppose you have to ask what is the value in refactoring (stability, better user experience, testability etc..) - and provide estimates after you've done some research.  Crucially here though, there is value in refactoring, and isn't a simple case of updating legacy code, which shouldn't be pressured with a timescale at this stage.

Comment: @MarkKeen I agree completely, but the various points of view would be the project has been in tow for quite a few years now and was long due for an update.  They brought me in as a junior without prior experience just to keep an eye on things, they didn't expect me to find what I did and they're not wholeheartedly willing to pour significant resources into changing it.  I'm also not in the best position to do this significant change, I'm not a moron but I'm still a junior after all.  I'm still focusing on getting bug fixes out there while learning project refactoring principles.